# E2fsprogs undefined reference to symbol - LFS

Tags: compiling, dynamic-linking, lfs

I'm building an LFS system, and I've gotten to [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/e2fsprogs.html) page, but when I run `make` it says:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/sources/e2fsprogs-1.42.13/build/e2fsck'
LD e2fsck
/usr/bin/ld: journal.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uuid_unparse@@UUID_1.0'
../lib/libuuid.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:409: recipe for target 'e2fsck' failed
make[2]: *** [e2fsck] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/e2fsprogs-1.42.13/build/e2fsck'
Makefile:383: recipe for target 'all-progs-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-progs-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/e2fsprogs-1.42.13/build'
Makefile:319: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found this github issue: https://github.com/garlik/4store/issues/75 but I don't know if that applies to this or not.

What's going wrong here, and how can fix this?

DSO missing from command line

**EDIT:**

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096807/dso-missing-from-command-line) it sounds like it has something to do with the dynamic linker .

On [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/adjusting.html) page, it says:

> First, backup the /tools linker, and replace it with the adjusted linker we made in chapter 5. We'll also create a link to its counterpart in /tools/$(gcc -dumpmachine)/bin:

Was there something I was suppose to do at that point besides running the commands listed on the page?

Comment: Anyone know whats going on? I'm still stuck and would really like to continue

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem if building [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) with [libuuid](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid) and [libblkid](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libblkid) from [util-linux](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) without setting up the [pkg-config](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) environment properly:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=${SYSROOT}
```

Please also refer to the [Autotool Cross Build Reference](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html).